# How to run a shell command for each member of a list in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

This should be a very basic thing but I can't figure it out again..

I have files dir1/a, dir2/a, dir3/a, dir4/a, ..
I want to do `ls -l` for those files but only for a given directory list.

```
dir_list := dir1 dir2 dir3
$(dir_list) : % : 
    $(shell ls -l $@/a)
```

when I do `make` it gives me

```
make: 'dir1' is up to date.
```

note that I want to do this `ls -l` regardless of the dependency(time).

ADD : after realizing the target rule is not executed (because it already exists), I tried this one but doesn't work either (shows only the first directory).

```
dir_list := dir1 dir2 dir3
.PHONY : $(dir_list)
$(dir_list) :
    ls -l $@/a

$make 
ls -l dir1/a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ckim ckim 0  7??  8 10:33 dir1/a
```

Comment: What do you want if `a` is absent from one of the directories in the list?

Comment: I can run it even though that's the case. (actually, there'll be no such case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second solution is almost perfect. The only small problem is that make, by default, tries to build the first declared target (`dir1` in your case). Solution: add a phony target that depends on all others and that is also the first:

```
dir_list := dir1 dir2 dir3

.PHONY: all $(dir_list)

all: $(dir_list)

$(dir_list):
    ls -l $@/a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude solution:

```
all: scan_dir1 scan_dir2 scan_dir3

scan_%:
    @ls -l $*/a
```

But since we're not actually building files named "scan_dir1", "scan_dir2", "scan_dir3", it is better form to declare these targets `PHONY`. *But* Make doesn't consider implicit rules when trying to build PHONY targets, so the rule above won't work. But a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) will:

```
SCANS := scan_dir1 scan_dir2 scan_dir3

.PHONY: $(SCANS)

all: $(SCANS)

$(SCANS): scan_%:
    @ls -l $*/a
```

Now we make a slight change, to construct the list of scans from the list of directories:

```
dir_list := dir1 dir2 dir3
SCANS := $(addprefix scan_,$(dir_list))
```

We could make further changes to handle the case when one of the `a` files is missing, but that can wait for another day.

Comment: Thanks! this works too! (I chose the other answer because it was more to the point using my example code.. )